# bibliography-specific formatting of multiple book entries for same author

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-dw

I have a book with multiple bibliographies. My editor wants a special formatting for one of the bibliographies. Below is an MWE and below the MWE the explanation:

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{book}


\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
citereset=chapter,
edstringincitations=false,
bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{quellen.bib}
@incollection{inproc1,
    Author = {Test Author},
    crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {1--10},
    Title = {Testing the Title}}

@incollection{inproc2,
    Author = {Test Author},
    crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {10--20},
    Title = {Testing the second Title}}
@incollection{inproc4,
    Author = {Test Author},
    crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {10--20},
    Title = {Testing the third Title}}
@incollection{inproc5,
    Author = {Test Author},
    crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {10--20},
    Title = {Testing the forth Title}}
@incollection{inproc6,
    Author = {Test Author},
    crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {10--20},
    Title = {Testing the fifth Title}}
@collection{proc,
    Editor = {Senor Editor and Senora Editora},
    Publisher = {Any Publisher},
    Title = {My Proceedings},
    Year = {2013},
    shorttitle = {Shorttitle}}

@inproceedings{inproc3,
    Author  = {Nother Author},
    Publisher = {Nother Publisher},
    Title   = {In Some Other Proceedings},
    Maintitle = {Main Title of Other Proceedings},
    Year     = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
    @incollection{inproc12,
        Author = {Test Author},
        crossref = {proc},
        Pages = {1--10},
        Title = {Testing the Title}}

    @incollection{inproc22,
        Author = {Test Author},
        crossref = {proc},
        Pages = {10--20},
        Title = {Testing the second Title}}

    @incollection{inproc42,
        Author = {Test Author},
        crossref = {proc},
        Pages = {10--20},
        Title = {Testing the third Title}}

    @incollection{inproc52,
        Author = {Test Author},
        crossref = {proc},
        Pages = {10--20},
        Title = {Testing the forth Title}}

    @incollection{inproc62,
        Author = {Test Author},
        crossref = {proc},
        Pages = {10--20},
        Title = {Testing the fifth Title}}

    @collection{proc2,
        Editor = {Senor Editor and Senora Editora},
        Publisher = {Any Publisher},
        Title = {My Proceedings},
        Year = {2013},
        shorttitle = {Shorttitle}}

    @inproceedings{inproc32,
        Author  = {Nother Author},
        Publisher = {Nother Publisher},
        Title   = {In Some Other Proceedings},
        Maintitle = {Main Title of Other Proceedings},
        Year     = {2001},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
\addbibresource{quellen.bib}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\cite{inproc42}\cite{inproc52}\cite{inproc62}
Test \cite{inproc12} and \cite{inproc22} and \cite{inproc32}
\cite{inproc4}\cite{inproc5}\cite{inproc6}
Test \cite{inproc1} and \cite{inproc2} and \cite{inproc3}
\printbibliography[keyword=literatur,title=Specially formatted bibliography]
\printbibliography[keyword=quellen,title=Plain old'n sturdy bibliography]
\end{document}
```

And my biber.conf looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<sourcemap>
  <maps datatype="bibtex" bmap_overwrite="1">
    <map>
      <per_datasource>literatur.bib</per_datasource>
      <map_step map_field_set="KEYWORDS" map_field_value="literatur"/>
    </map>
    <map>
      <per_datasource>quellen.bib</per_datasource>
      <map_step map_field_set="KEYWORDS" map_field_value="quellen"/>
    </map>        
  </maps>
</sourcemap>
</config>
```

The Specially formatted bibliography looks currently like this:

[image]

The first entry of the list for one author should also appear in the same formatting as the second, third..., i.e. it should start in the line below the author and have a dash in front of it

```
Author, Test:
  - Testing the fifth title ...
  - Testing the forth title ...
```

Comment: But you don't want that to happen for authors that are only listed with one work, right? That means that at the point of typesetting (the first occurrence of) the author name you already have to know if there are going to follow other works by the same author. The information is, however, not available at the point of typesetting the author name.

Comment: If you want this also for authors with only one work, have a look at  [`biblatex-philosophy`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-philosophy)'s `philosophy-modern`.

Comment: argh, that's too sad. I think it will be ok if it is this way also for authors with only one work. Now the problem is, for the other bibliographies I would like to use biblatex-dw, because of lots of other weird formatting problems already solved with biblatex-dw. Is this possible at all?

Comment: Wait, a minute. There might be away around that. Let me check.

Comment: Normally we could use `\ifsingletitle` to check if there are more works by one author. But since we split the bibliography we have no way of knowing if the other works also go into the same bibliography.... Can you explain how the two bibliography lists differ? Could we maybe use a different method than `keywords`? Do you have to be able to cite sources for both bibliographies in the same chapter?

Comment: The bibliography is split in categories: published sources, sources, literature. I am citing works from these categories in all chapters of the book, but I need separate bibliographies for the categories. The solution I have now is to have the categories in different bib files and annotate them with keywords with the biber functionality, so that I can use \printbibliography[keyword=...] to split them. So all works with the same keyword (AND in the same file) go into the same bibliography. I am open to other ways of achieving that.

Comment: Mhhh. Unfortunately, all solutions that depend on the 'unqiue' features that Biber provides cannot distinguish different `keywords`, so they can't be applied, unfortunately. So my initial idea won't work.

Comment: Are there any other fields we could use for this?

Comment: Not that I know, and even if you could use other fields, Biber would not be able to use them for disambiguation either. We would have to have the works in different refsections for Biber to be able to separate them properly, but is impracticable for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62792/discussion-between-philipp-and-moewe).

Comment: Not an automatic solution. But if you don't have *that* many references that need this, you could add `@misc` entries containing just the author and `nocite` them. Adjust the `misc` driver so it ends with a colon rather than a period. You can use a source map to add the `keyword` based on data source. At least this would give you the output you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow. I can't believe this actually works...

Here's a possible way forward.

Set the `biblatex` option `minxrefs=2` (hopefully you are not already using this).

We use a complicated set of source maps for the heavy lifting. We set `keywords` based on the `bib` file. We create a new entry of type `specialauthor` containing just the `author` and `keyword` field for every entry type in `literatur.bib`. We set `xref` to point to this new entry for every item in `literatur.bib`.

We create a new driver to handle the entries of type `specialauthor`.

We turn off the printing of the `editor` and `translator` strings when printing `\bibnamedash` in the special bibliography.

It's not thoroughly tested, so I'd be careful. And it will definitely give odd results if you are using custom name strings. But at least it doesn't require you to make any changes to your `bib` data.

And putting it all together:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
edstringincitations=false,
bibencoding=utf8,
minxrefs=2]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{quellen.bib}
@incollection{inproc1,
    Author = {Test Author},
    crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {1--10},
    Title = {Testing the Title}}

@incollection{inproc2,
    Author = {Test Author},
    crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {10--20},
    Title = {Testing the second Title}}
@incollection{inproc4,
    Author = {Test Author},
    crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {10--20},
    Title = {Testing the third Title}}
@incollection{inproc5,
    Author = {Test Author},
    crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {10--20},
    Title = {Testing the forth Title}}
@incollection{inproc6,
    Author = {Test Author},
    crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {10--20},
    Title = {Testing the fifth Title}}
@collection{proc,
    Editor = {Senor Editor and Senora Editora},
    Publisher = {Any Publisher},
    Title = {My Proceedings},
    Year = {2013},
    shorttitle = {Shorttitle}}

@inproceedings{inproc3,
    Author  = {Nother Author},
    Publisher = {Nother Publisher},
    Title   = {In Some Other Proceedings},
    Maintitle = {Main Title of Other Proceedings},
    Year     = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@incollection{inproc12,
    Author = {Test Author},
    crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {1--10},
    Title = {Testing the Title}}

@incollection{inproc22,
    Author = {Test Author},
    crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {10--20},
    Title = {Testing the second Title}}

@incollection{inproc42,
    Author = {Test Author},
    crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {10--20},
    Title = {Testing the third Title}}

@incollection{inproc52,
    Author = {Test Author},
    crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {10--20},
    Title = {Testing the forth Title}}

@incollection{inproc62,
    Author = {Test Author},
    crossref = {proc},
    Pages = {10--20},
    Title = {Testing the fifth Title}}

@collection{proc2,
    Editor = {Editor, Senor and Editora, Senora},
    Publisher = {Any Publisher},
    Title = {My Proceedings},
    Year = {2013},
    shorttitle = {Shorttitle}}

@collection{proc3,
    Editor = {Editor, Senor and Editora, Senora},
    Publisher = {Any Publisher},
    Title = {Your Proceedings},
    Year = {2013},
    shorttitle = {Shorttitle}}

@inproceedings{inproc32,
    Author  = {Nother Author},
    Publisher = {Nother Publisher},
    Title   = {In Some Other Proceedings},
    Maintitle = {Main Title of Other Proceedings},
    Year     = {2001},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
\addbibresource{quellen.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{quellen.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={quellen}]
    }
    \map{
      \perdatasource{literatur.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={literatur}]
      \step[fieldset=options, fieldvalue={,}, append]
      \step[fieldsource=options, notmatch=\regexp{.*useauthor\s*=\s*false.*}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{(.*)}, final]
      \step[entrynew={$1}, entrynewtype=specialauthor]
      \step[entrytarget={$1}, fieldset={author}, fieldvalue={$1}]
      \step[entrytarget={$1}, fieldset={keywords}, fieldvalue={literatur}]
      \step[fieldset=xref, fieldvalue={$1}]
    }
    \map{
      \perdatasource{literatur.bib}
      \step[notfield=author, final]
      \step[fieldset=options, fieldvalue={,}, append]
      \step[fieldsource=options, notmatch=\regexp{.*useeditor\s*=\s*false.*}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=editor, match=\regexp{(.*)}, final]
      \step[entrynew={$1}, entrynewtype=specialauthor]
      \step[entrytarget={$1}, fieldset={editor}, fieldvalue={$1}]
      \step[entrytarget={$1}, fieldset={keywords}, fieldvalue={literatur}]
      \step[fieldset=xref, fieldvalue={$1}]
    }
    \map{
      \perdatasource{literatur.bib}
      \step[notfield=author, final]
      \step[notfield=editor, final]
      \step[fieldset=options, fieldvalue={,}, append]
      \step[fieldsource=options, notmatch=\regexp{.*usetranslator\s*=\s*false.*}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=options, match=\regexp{.*usetranslator.*}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=translator, match=\regexp{(.*)}, final]
      \step[entrynew={$1}, entrynewtype=specialauthor]
      \step[entrytarget={$1}, fieldset={translator}, fieldvalue={$1}]
      \step[entrytarget={$1}, fieldset={options}, fieldvalue={usetranslator=true}]
      \step[entrytarget={$1}, fieldset={keywords}, fieldvalue={literatur}]
      \step[fieldset=xref, fieldvalue={$1}]
    }
  }
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{specialauthor}{%
  \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addcolon}%
  \ifbool{cbx:idemfull}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
     \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {}
       {\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock}}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifkeyword{literatur}}
    and
    not test {\ifentrytype{specialauthor}}
    and
    test {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
    and
    not test {\iffirstonpage}
  }
    {\renewbibmacro*{translator+othersstrg}{}%
     \renewbibmacro*{editor+othersstrg}{}}
    {}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\cite{inproc42}\cite{inproc52}\cite{inproc62}
Test \cite{inproc12} and \cite{inproc22} and \cite{inproc32}
\cite{inproc4}\cite{inproc5}\cite{inproc6}
Test \cite{inproc1} and \cite{inproc2} and \cite{inproc3}
\cite{proc2,proc3}
\printbibliography[keyword=literatur,title=Specially formatted bibliography]
\printbibliography[keyword=quellen,title=Plain old'n sturdy bibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Now that is a clever solution. Since we use the name of the author as entrykey this gave me some problem with non-ASCII author names. Potentially this also has trouble if I give the name of an author in two formats (`Anne Elk` vs `Elk, Anne`). But apart from that this really is impressive stuff.

Comment: Yes I wondered about this. To be honest I was surprised it worked with spaces. It does work OK with commas though. I tested that much.

Comment: I was surprised by the fact that spaces and commas went through that smoothly as well.

Comment: Hmm is minxrefs quite new? I am getting Package keyval error: minxrefs undefined. Should be solvable easily, let me see

Comment: epic, thank you! This need biblatex > 2.4, just for other people's information

Comment: @moewe Can you elaborate why it has problems with the case when the name of the author appears in multiple formats? I have "Gauck, Joachim" and "Gauck, Joachim and others" and "Gauck, Joachim and Heldt, Thomas and Leefhelm, Kirsten". This gives problems. Is there a way around it?

Comment: @Philipp In these cases I wouldn't have expected the code to treat all these as the same. You will only get the 'next line style' if all authors are the same. In this case here the set of authors is distinct.

Comment: Yes, it's really just a hack that happens to work. It relies on the author field been identical in each case. The handling of useauthor (and similar) is also pretty fragile.

Comment: I have posted a follow-up question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383838/bibliography-specific-formatting-of-multiple-book-entries-for-same-author-solu . I really do not understand why it doesn't work in this case, since the author names are exactly the same. Any help would be very much appreciated.