# biblatex - always print @collection items separately, also if there is only one @incollection item referencing it

Tags: biblatex, formatting

I have a bibliography with some special formatting that prints only the shorttitle of the referenced collection for @incollection items.

However, it does so only for @incollection items, where multiple @incollection items exist referencing the same @collection item.

I want to @collection item always to appear as a separate item in the bibliography, regardless of how many @incollection items reference it.

AND

I want the formatting of the @incollection item always be the same, regardless of how many @incollection items exist for the referenced @collection.

See MWE below and image for explanation.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
hyperref=true,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
citereset=chapter,
edstringincitations=false,
bibencoding=utf8,
minxrefs=2]{biblatex}

% ----------- mistake is somewhere in here ------------
%% bilbiography driver to display only shorttitle of referenced collection for incollection items
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
    \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \newunit
    \printlist{language}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{in:}%
    \iffieldundef{crossref}
    {\usebibmacro{crossref:full}}
    {\usebibmacro{crossref:label}}
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
    \iffieldundef{crossref}
    {\usebibmacro{crossref:extrainfo}}
    {}
    \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
    \usebibmacro{pageref}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\newbibmacro{crossref:full}{%
    \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
        \printfield{part}}
    {}%
    \newunit
    \printfield{volumes}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{series+number}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{note}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \printlist{organization}%
    \newunit
    \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}}

\newbibmacro{crossref:label}{%
    \entrydata{\strfield{crossref}}
    {\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}%
        \printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit*{\addspace}%
        %\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}%
        \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
        \printfield[shorttitle]{labeltitle}}}

\newbibmacro{crossref:extrainfo}{%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}}

% ----------- mistake is somewhere above here ------------

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{albrechtbirkner,
    crossref = {kampmann},
    author = {Albrecht-Birkner, Veronika},
    title = {Die Zwei-Reiche-Lehre in der DDR: Vortrag im Rahmen der Tagung Die lutherische Zwei-Reiche-Lehre in politischen Kontexten des 20. Jahrhunderts},
    shorttitle = {Reiche},
    gender = {sf}
}
@incollection{banchelli2008,
    crossref = {cambi2008},
    author = {Banchelli, Eva},
    title = {Ostalgie: eine vorläufige Bilanz},
    shorttitle = {Ostalgie},
    gender = {sf}
}

@collection{cambi2008,
    year = {2008},
    title = {Gedächtnis und Identität: Die deutsche Literatur nach der Vereinigung},
    address = {Würzburg},
    isbn = {382603788X},
    editor = {Cambi, Fabrizio},
    shorttitle = {Gedächtnis},
    gender = {sm}
}

@collection{kampmann,
    year = {2017},
    title = {Angewandtes Luthertum?},
    address = {Gütersloh},
    isbn = {382603788X},
    editor = {Kampmann, Jürgen and Otte, Hans},
    shorttitle = {Luthertum},
    gender = {pp}
}
@incollection{pelz2015,
    crossref = {kampmann},
    year = {2017},
    title = {Von der Deutschen Demokratischen Repunlik zur deutschen Pastorenrepublik? Mecklenburgische und Pommersche, evangelisch-lutherische Predigten von 1989/90 als Spiegel der Interpretationen einer lutherischen Zwei-Reiche-Lehre im 20. Jahrhundert},
    author = {Pelz, Birge-Dorothea},
    shorttitle = {Kirche}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \cite{pelz2015,banchelli2008,albrechtbirkner}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Image:

[image]

In case 1, the special formatting correctly applies, as there are more than 1 @incollection items for the @collection KAMPMANN.

In case 2, thereis only BANCHELLI referencing CAMBI, and CAMBI does not appear in the bibliography. This shoudl be changed as described above.

Comment: Try the option `mincrossrefs=1`. The default is `mincrossrefs=2`. So you only get the `crossref`'d `collection` if there are two or more `@incollection`s `crossref`ing it.

Comment: Ah, but that collides with the other formatting specialty here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383178/bibliography-specific-formatting-of-multiple-book-entries-for-same-author Darn!

Comment: Now all these special wishes start biting each other in the foot

Comment: Does it? Blast, I thought `minxrefs` and `mincrossrefs` would be independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
mincrossrefs=1
```

you can make sure that all `crossref`'d entries always appear in the bibliography even if they were not cited.

The default is `microssrefs=2`, so there need to be two or more `@incollections` `crossref`ing the same `@collection`.

Fortunately, `microssrefs` and `minxrefs` are independent so that you can still use David's answer to [bibliography-specific formatting of multiple book entries for same author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383178/35864).