# bibliography-specific formatting of multiple book entries for same author - solution quirk 2

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-dw

This question is related to the question [bibliography-specific formatting of multiple book entries for same author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383178/bibliography-specific-formatting-of-multiple-book-entries-for-same-author), which has a really nice solution, but when applied to my data, there is a SECOND strange quirk related to the author.

It happens when the list of works of one author is very long and spans more than one page. The formatting on the second page will be wrong, as seen in the following screenshots:

[image]
[image]

On the second page where LOHSE, Henry is printed, the first entry is not placed in the dash list.

Is there any way to place this entry also in the dash list?

I think this has to do with the /iffirstonpage command that is used.
Thanks for the help!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
edstringincitations=false,
bibencoding=utf8,
minxrefs=2]{biblatex}
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{quellen.bib}
@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock7.12.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and Schmachtel, Jochen and others},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 7.12.1989 zu Jes 43,1-3a},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 7.12.1989}
}


@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock8.2.1990,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and Schmachtel, Jochen and others},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 8.2.1990 zu Lk 9,61.62 und Mt 13,31f.},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 8.2.1990}
}


@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock9.11.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    year = {9}, month = {1}, day = {9},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 9.11.1989 zu Lk 7,11-16; 1. Joh 3,18f.},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 9.11.1989}
}
@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock26.10.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and Heldt, Thomas and Leefhelm, Kirsten},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 26.10.1989 zu Mt 5,44-47a},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 26.10.1989}
}


@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock30.11.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 30.11.1989 zu Lk 21,34-36},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 30.11.1989}
}
@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock23.11.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 23.11.1989 zu Jer 8,4-7},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 23.11.1989}
}
@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock2.11.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 2.11.1989 zu Mt 7,15-17},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 2.11.1989}
}
@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock19.10.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 19.10.1989 zu Amos 5,21-24},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 19.10.1989}
}
@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock11.10.1990,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    title = {Gottesdienst am 11.10.1990 in Rostock, St. Marien: Plakat und Presseerklärung},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Gottesdienst am 11.10.1990}
}


@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock14.12.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    title = {Predigt am 14.12.1989 zu Lk 1,46-56},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 14.12.1989}
}
@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock1.2.1990,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    title = {Predigt am 1.2.1990 zu Ex 3,7.10-14},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 1.2.1990}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
    @book{ms3140m1.11.11,
        author = {Lohse, Henry},
        title = {Fragebogen vom 1.11.2011},
        shorttitle = {Fragebogen}
    }
    @book{ms3140m30.3.1989,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 30.3.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 30.3.1989 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m18.6.1989,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 18.6.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 18.6.1989 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m18.7.1989,
    author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 18.7.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 18.6.1989 }
}
    @book{ms3140m18.8.1989,
    author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 18.8.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 18.6.1989 }
}
    @book{ms3140m18.9.1989,
    author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 18.9.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 18.6.1989 }
}
    @book{ms3140m18.10.1989,
    author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 18.10.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 18.6.1989 }
}
    @book{ms3140m18.11.1989,
    author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 18.11.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 18.6.1989 }
}
    @book{ms3140m1.10.1989,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 1.10.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 1.10.1989 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m15.10.1989,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 15.10.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 15.10.1989 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m22.10.1989,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 22.10.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 22.10.1989 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m24.12.1989,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 24.12.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 24.12.1989 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m4.3.1990,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 4.3.1990 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 4.3.1990 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m25.3.1990,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 25.3.1990 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 25.3.1990 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m1.7.1990,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 1.7.1990 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 1.7.1990 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m7.10.1990,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 7.10.1990 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 7.10.1990 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m14.10.1990,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 14.10.1990 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 14.10.1990 }
    }
@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock7.12.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and Schmachtel, Jochen and others},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 7.12.1989 zu Jes 43,1-3a},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 7.12.1989}
}


@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock8.2.1990,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and Schmachtel, Jochen and others},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 8.2.1990 zu Lk 9,61.62 und Mt 13,31f.},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 8.2.1990}
}


@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock9.11.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    year = {9}, month = {1}, day = {9},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 9.11.1989 zu Lk 7,11-16; 1. Joh 3,18f.},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 9.11.1989}
}
@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock26.10.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and Heldt, Thomas and Leefhelm, Kirsten},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 26.10.1989 zu Mt 5,44-47a},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 26.10.1989}
}


@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock30.11.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 30.11.1989 zu Lk 21,34-36},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 30.11.1989}
}
@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock23.11.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 23.11.1989 zu Jer 8,4-7},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 23.11.1989}
}
@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock2.11.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 2.11.1989 zu Mt 7,15-17},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 2.11.1989}
}
@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock19.10.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 19.10.1989 zu Amos 5,21-24},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 19.10.1989}
}
@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock11.10.1990,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    title = {Gottesdienst am 11.10.1990 in Rostock, St. Marien: Plakat und Presseerklärung},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Gottesdienst am 11.10.1990}
}


@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock14.12.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    title = {Predigt am 14.12.1989 zu Lk 1,46-56},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 14.12.1989}
}
@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock1.2.1990,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    title = {Predigt am 1.2.1990 zu Ex 3,7.10-14},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 1.2.1990}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
\addbibresource{quellen.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map{
            \perdatasource{quellen.bib}
            \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={quellen}]
        }
        \map{
            \perdatasource{literatur.bib}
            \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={literatur}]
            \step[fieldset=options, fieldvalue={,}, append]
            \step[fieldsource=options, notmatch=\regexp{.*useauthor\s*=\s*false.*}, final]
            \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{(.*)}, final]
            \step[entrynew={$1}, entrynewtype=specialauthor]
            \step[entrytarget={$1}, fieldset={author}, fieldvalue={$1}]
            \step[entrytarget={$1}, fieldset={keywords}, fieldvalue={literatur}]
            \step[fieldset=xref, fieldvalue={$1}]
        }
        \map{
            \perdatasource{literatur.bib}
            \step[notfield=author, final]
            \step[fieldset=options, fieldvalue={,}, append]
            \step[fieldsource=options, notmatch=\regexp{.*useeditor\s*=\s*false.*}, final]
            \step[fieldsource=editor, match=\regexp{(.*)}, final]
            \step[entrynew={$1}, entrynewtype=specialauthor]
            \step[entrytarget={$1}, fieldset={editor}, fieldvalue={$1}]
            \step[entrytarget={$1}, fieldset={keywords}, fieldvalue={literatur}]
            \step[fieldset=xref, fieldvalue={$1}]
        }
        \map{
            \perdatasource{literatur.bib}
            \step[notfield=author, final]
            \step[notfield=editor, final]
            \step[fieldset=options, fieldvalue={,}, append]
            \step[fieldsource=options, notmatch=\regexp{.*usetranslator\s*=\s*false.*}, final]
            \step[fieldsource=options, match=\regexp{.*usetranslator.*}, final]
            \step[fieldsource=translator, match=\regexp{(.*)}, final]
            \step[entrynew={$1}, entrynewtype=specialauthor]
            \step[entrytarget={$1}, fieldset={translator}, fieldvalue={$1}]
            \step[entrytarget={$1}, fieldset={options}, fieldvalue={usetranslator=true}]
            \step[entrytarget={$1}, fieldset={keywords}, fieldvalue={literatur}]
            \step[fieldset=xref, fieldvalue={$1}]
        }
    }
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{specialauthor}{%
    \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addcolon}%
    \ifbool{cbx:idemfull}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
        \ifnameundef{labelname}
        {}
        {\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock}}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        test {\ifkeyword{literatur}}
        and
        not test {\ifentrytype{specialauthor}}
        and
        test {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
        and
        not test {\iffirstonpage}
    }
    {\renewbibmacro*{translator+othersstrg}{}%
        \renewbibmacro*{editor+othersstrg}{}}
    {}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \cite{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock7.12.1989,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock8.2.1990,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock9.11.1989,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock26.10.1989,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock30.11.1989,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock23.11.1989,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock2.11.1989,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock19.10.1989,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock11.10.1990,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock14.12.1989,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock1.2.1990},
    \cite{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock7.12.1989,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock8.2.1990,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock9.11.1989,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock26.10.1989,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock30.11.1989,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock23.11.1989,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock2.11.1989,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock19.10.1989,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock11.10.1990,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock14.12.1989,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock1.2.1990}\cite{ms3140m30.3.1989,ms3140m18.6.1989,ms3140m1.10.1989,ms3140m15.10.1989}\nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[keyword=literatur,title=Specially formatted bibliography]
    \printbibliography[keyword=quellen,title=Plain old'n sturdy bibliography]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you think of

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
edsuper=true,
namefont=smallcaps,
useprefix=true,
ibidemfont=smallcaps,
idemfont=smallcaps,
idembibformat=dash,
shorthandibid=true,
backref=false,
backrefstyle=none,
isbn=false,
backend=biber,
edstringincitations=false,
bibencoding=utf8,
minxrefs=2]{biblatex}
\listfiles

\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map{
            \perdatasource{quellen.bib}
            \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={quellen}]
        }
        \map{
            \perdatasource{literatur.bib}
            \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={literatur}]
        }
    }
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifkeyword{literatur}}
              and (test {\iffirstonpage}
                   or not test {\ifdefequal\bbx@beforelasthash\bbx@lasthash})}
    {\item\bibnamedash}
    {\addcolon\space}%
}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \let\bbx@beforelasthash\bbx@lasthash
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{quellen.bib}
@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock7.12.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and Schmachtel, Jochen and others},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 7.12.1989 zu Jes 43,1-3a},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 7.12.1989}
}


@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock8.2.1990,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and Schmachtel, Jochen and others},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 8.2.1990 zu Lk 9,61.62 und Mt 13,31f.},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 8.2.1990}
}


@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock9.11.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    year = {9}, month = {1}, day = {9},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 9.11.1989 zu Lk 7,11-16; 1. Joh 3,18f.},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 9.11.1989}
}
@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock26.10.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and Heldt, Thomas and Leefhelm, Kirsten},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 26.10.1989 zu Mt 5,44-47a},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 26.10.1989}
}


@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock30.11.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 30.11.1989 zu Lk 21,34-36},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 30.11.1989}
}
@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock23.11.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 23.11.1989 zu Jer 8,4-7},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 23.11.1989}
}
@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock2.11.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 2.11.1989 zu Mt 7,15-17},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 2.11.1989}
}
@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock19.10.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 19.10.1989 zu Amos 5,21-24},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 19.10.1989}
}
@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock11.10.1990,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    title = {Gottesdienst am 11.10.1990 in Rostock, St. Marien: Plakat und Presseerklärung},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Gottesdienst am 11.10.1990}
}


@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock14.12.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    title = {Predigt am 14.12.1989 zu Lk 1,46-56},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 14.12.1989}
}
@book{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock1.2.1990,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    title = {Predigt am 1.2.1990 zu Ex 3,7.10-14},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 1.2.1990}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
    @book{ms3140m1.11.11,
        author = {Lohse, Henry},
        title = {Fragebogen vom 1.11.2011},
        shorttitle = {Fragebogen}
    }
    @book{ms3140m30.3.1989,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 30.3.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 30.3.1989 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m18.6.1989,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 18.6.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 18.6.1989 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m18.7.1989,
    author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 18.7.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 18.6.1989 }
}
    @book{ms3140m18.8.1989,
    author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 18.8.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 18.6.1989 }
}
    @book{ms3140m18.9.1989,
    author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 18.9.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 18.6.1989 }
}
    @book{ms3140m18.10.1989,
    author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 18.10.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 18.6.1989 }
}
    @book{ms3140m18.11.1989,
    author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 18.11.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 18.6.1989 }
}
    @book{ms3140m1.10.1989,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 1.10.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 1.10.1989 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m15.10.1989,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 15.10.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 15.10.1989 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m22.10.1989,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 22.10.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 22.10.1989 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m24.12.1989,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 24.12.1989 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 24.12.1989 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m4.3.1990,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 4.3.1990 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 4.3.1990 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m25.3.1990,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 25.3.1990 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 25.3.1990 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m1.7.1990,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 1.7.1990 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 1.7.1990 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m7.10.1990,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 7.10.1990 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 7.10.1990 }
    }
    @book{ms3140m14.10.1990,
        author = {Lohse, Henry}, title = {Predigt am 14.10.1990 }, shorttitle={Predigt am 14.10.1990 }
    }
@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock7.12.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and Schmachtel, Jochen and others},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 7.12.1989 zu Jes 43,1-3a},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 7.12.1989}
}


@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock8.2.1990,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and Schmachtel, Jochen and others},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 8.2.1990 zu Lk 9,61.62 und Mt 13,31f.},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 8.2.1990}
}


@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock9.11.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    year = {9}, month = {1}, day = {9},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 9.11.1989 zu Lk 7,11-16; 1. Joh 3,18f.},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 9.11.1989}
}
@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock26.10.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and Heldt, Thomas and Leefhelm, Kirsten},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 26.10.1989 zu Mt 5,44-47a},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 26.10.1989}
}


@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock30.11.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 30.11.1989 zu Lk 21,34-36},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 30.11.1989}
}
@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock23.11.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 23.11.1989 zu Jer 8,4-7},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 23.11.1989}
}
@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock2.11.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 2.11.1989 zu Mt 7,15-17},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 2.11.1989}
}
@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock19.10.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim},
    title = {Predigt in der Rostocker Donnerstagsandacht am 19.10.1989 zu Amos 5,21-24},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 19.10.1989}
}
@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock11.10.1990,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    title = {Gottesdienst am 11.10.1990 in Rostock, St. Marien: Plakat und Presseerklärung},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Gottesdienst am 11.10.1990}
}


@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock14.12.1989,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    title = {Predigt am 14.12.1989 zu Lk 1,46-56},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 14.12.1989}
}
@book{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock1.2.1990,
    author = {Gauck, Joachim and others},
    title = {Predigt am 1.2.1990 zu Ex 3,7.10-14},
    address = {Rostock},
    shorttitle = {Predigt am 1.2.1990}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
\addbibresource{quellen.bib}

\begin{document}
    \cite{1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock7.12.1989,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock8.2.1990,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock9.11.1989,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock26.10.1989,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock30.11.1989,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock23.11.1989,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock2.11.1989,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock19.10.1989,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock11.10.1990,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock14.12.1989,1wendearchivderuniversitatrostock1.2.1990},
    \cite{wendearchivderuniversitatrostock7.12.1989,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock8.2.1990,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock9.11.1989,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock26.10.1989,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock30.11.1989,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock23.11.1989,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock2.11.1989,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock19.10.1989,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock11.10.1990,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock14.12.1989,wendearchivderuniversitatrostock1.2.1990}\cite{ms3140m30.3.1989,ms3140m18.6.1989,ms3140m1.10.1989,ms3140m15.10.1989}\nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[keyword=literatur,title=Specially formatted bibliography]
    \printbibliography[keyword=quellen,title=Plain old'n sturdy bibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

I could not quite figure out a way to get solve the issue with the code you are using right now, because I think a solution would have to insert the `@specialauthor` again at the beginning of the page, so I tried to find a new solution.

The idea is to simply insert an `\item` command instead of the usual colon and space after the name for the first entry of a particular author.

Comment: Looks very nice, only mistake: it does not print a colon after the author name in the specially formatted bibliography. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @Philipp Add `\addcolon` to the `{\item\bibnamedash}` so that it reads `{\addcolon\item\bibnamedash}`.